# Print Google Calendar showing time blocks but not names of events

Tags: google-calendar

Let's say I want to print a week from Google Calendar and show to someone else for scheduling purposes but don't want to show the names of the events.

Is there an easier way than cutting and pasting into Microsoft Paint and covering the names with colored squares?

I use Windows 10.

Comment: Can you simply share your "free/busy" information with them?

Answer (score 3):

Install [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) or something similar in your browser.

Open it up on the calendar page and go to Edit CSS at the bottom.

Enter this -

`.evt-lk {
 display:none;
}`

Save it. Close Stylebot. Print it.

Open up Stylebot and comment out (see below) what you just did so it'll be around next time you need it but it won't mess stuff up in the meantime.

`.evt-lk {
    /* display: none; */
}`

Comment: Google Calendar CSS style codes evolve; I used https://selectorgadget.com to get the updated styles. Then instead of Stylebot, I applied this technique with Custom Style Script (https://mybrowseraddon.com/custom-style-script.html) for Firefox). With these adaptations, this solution works great for me!

Comment: What I love about this solution is that there is no need to make my private calendars public, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you make your calendar public, you can still hide details of the meetings. They show as *busy* or *free* depending on how you set that in the event.

Open a shared view of your calendar in an incognito/private-browsing (to appear as it would from a non authenticated user). Print it.

An example can be found [here](http://profs.etsmtl.ca/cfuhrman/).